# Highlight words in string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a bunch of text and i want to highlight some words on that text. I've search the stackoverflow website and came up with something that almost work.

PHP

```
function highlighter($str, $arr_word)
{
    foreach($arr_word as $vword) {
        $text = preg_replace("|($vword)|Ui", "<span class=highlight>$1</span>", $str);
    }

    return $text;
}

$lyrics = 'hello looking for';
$arr_accepted_keyword = array('hello', 'for');

echo highlighter($lyrics, $arr_accepted_keyword);
```

For some reason, it always highligths the last word, and not all the words. Why?

Comment: You should use `/` instead of `|` in your pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're highlighting each word in the *original* string, not the *updated* string.

```
function highlighter($str, $arr_word)
{
    foreach($arr_word as $vword) {
        $str = preg_replace("/($vword)/Ui", "<span class=highlight>$1</span>", $str);
    }

    return $str;
}

$lyrics = "hello, is it me you're looking for?";
$arr_accepted_keyword = array('hello', 'for');

echo highlighter($lyrics, $arr_accepted_keyword);
// "<span class=highlight>hello</span>, is it me you're looking <span class=highlight>for</span>?"
```